# Regarding computer forensics and forensic accounting

Tags: forensics

I feel that these 2 forensic fields should work hand in hand.

However, I do not have a background in computer science, but would like to upgrade myself to enhance my knowledge in this field.

There is too much information online, and I do not have the professional knowledge to know what is / is not relevant.

Dear experts, please advise me the fundamental knowledge required to formulate a plan to my learning.

Comment: I think the premise of your question is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: I think it's mainly due to the fact that I am looking for an entry point to a very broad field. I'm confident that I'll be asking more relevant questions in the future. Thanks for your opinion nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with learning how is storage organized, understanding file systems, how to recover deleted files with/without tool, learn about different file headers, imaging storage devices e.g. HDD, analyzing network traffic and dumps, analyzing system logs, etc.

Then you search for certifications like CHFI and refer their course outline for self study.

Comment: Thank you! that certainly gave me a clear direction on what I need to do!